# Strange issue with Citrix remote desktop and dual monitor

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display, citrix

Given the below:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- HP Compaq Pro 6300 SFF PC
- 2 identical HP monitors

I have a dual monitor setup which works perfectly, apart from the Citrix remote desktop.

Citrix says that it detected multi-monitor support. In fact when I remote in to a full-screen session and then minimize the screen and resize, then I can see that the window Citrix created has the same size as the 2 monitors, but for some reason it is only presented on one of the monitors. (I.e. one monitor shows half of the remote session, the other half on the other monitor is always hidden.)

The PC has a VGA and a displayport output. One of the monitors is connected directly with VGA, the other with a displayport->vga adapter.

A strange thing is that no matter which display is set to be the primary display in gnome, **Citrix always only shows itself on the monitor which is connected to the displayport output**. The only difference is that if the one plugged into the displayport is set as primary, then citrix shows the primary section of the remote desktop (i.e. the one with the system tray),  if the one plugged in the displayport is set as the secondary then citrix shows the secondary section of the remote desktop (which is normally an empty screen).

Normally this should work out of the box. Also no solutions to dual-monitor issues with citrix and linux I found on the web resolves this. Under Windows there are no issues with Citrix with the same setup.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

there may be multiple scenarios after what you comment

https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/receiver/windows/current-release/improve/dpi-scaling.html?_ga=2.141306353.27216297.1570132281-1814045878.1570132281

> Citrix says that it detected multi-monitor support.

CLiente Side?? or Server Side??

https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/382153-unuswindows-10-dual-monitor-setups-see-able-half-blacked-out-seamless-windows/

This really has nothing to do with how you connect the monitors, if your client side has 2 monitors, you can have the client re-scale the work screen. to take advantage of the two monitors.